# Some T2 spaces must have a small dense?

Tags: general-topology

If a Hausdorff space $\ X\ $ admits a dense subset $ A \hookrightarrow  X\ $ such that

$$|X|^{|A|}\ =\ |X|$$

then indeed $$|X| \leq |\text{End}_{\text{Top}}(X)|  \leq |X|^{|A|}\ = \ |X|.$$

It is the case of $\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Thus, if there is a  small  enough dense subspace, there are  not so many endomorphisms.

> Is the converse true?

Namely, suppose $|\text{End}_{\text{Top}}(X)|  = \ |X|.$ Is it true that there exists a dense subset $A$ such that $|X|^{|A|}\ =\ |X|$?

---

UPDATE: [Solved on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292738/some-t2-spaces-must-have-a-small-dense).

Comment: What is $\mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{Top}}(X)$?

Comment: You can construct group topologies on sets where the only endomorphism (homeomorphism of $X$ with itself, in my definition) is a translation. Make  such a space on a countable set and voila. No time to write it out now. Maybe later.

Comment: No, an endomorphism is just a continuous map $X \to X$.

Comment: Then $C(X,X)$ is more logical as a notation.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $\text{End}_{\text{Top}}(X)$ as in endomorphisms in the $\text{Top}$ category, i.e. a continuous $X\to X$ function. There's nothing wrong with the notation. Anyway this is an interesting question. Seems to be hard though.

Comment: @freakish so $\text{Hom}(X,X)$ essentially, in category theory terms.

Comment: I think that the condition $|C(X,X)| = |X|$ is quite rare. We always have $|C(X,X)| \ge |X|$.

Comment: Now posted on MO: [Some T2 spaces must have a small dense?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/292738)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*To kick it from the unanswered queue*)

As mentioned by the OP, this is solved on MO:  [Some T2 spaces must have a small dense?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292738/some-t2-spaces-must-have-a-small-dense)

---

@KeithKearnes 's solution:

> **Is the converse true?**
>
> No.
>
> The paper *[Constructions and Applications of Rigid Spaces, I](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90006-3)*, Advances in Mathematics 29 (1978), 89-130, by Kannan and Rajagopalan, describes a countaby infinite Hausdorff space $X$ such that the only continuous maps $f\colon X\to X$ are the constant maps and the identity map. Such a space satisfies 
>   $|\text{End}_{\text{Top}}(X)| = \omega  = \ |X|.$
>
> If $A\subseteq X$ is a subset such that $|X|^{|A|}=|X|=\omega$, then $A$ is forced to be finite, and therefore $A$ cannot be dense.